# New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer throws error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sts-securitytokenservice

I am trying to add a new trust token issuer to Sharepoint 2010,
however `New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer` throws:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation. CategoryInfo: InvalidData....

Any ideas why I may be getting this error?
The command is as follows:

```
$ap = New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name "MySTS" -Description "My Sts desc" -realm $realm -ImportTrustCertificate $stsCert -ClaimsMappings $mapUser,$mapRole -SignInUrl $signinUrl -IdentifierClaim $mapUser.InputClaimType
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove `-ImportTrustCertificate $stsCert` because I think this certificate is already imported.

Comment: Certificate parameter is required, what to do

Comment: I am trying to configure tokenissuer with same adfs server and same certificate,